# Поместить QProgressBar в QMessageBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, progress-bar

Можно ли поместить QProgressBar в QMessageBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно даже пытаться, тренируйте свое ООП (в частности абстракцию) - у QMessageBox своя работа. Для этого компания Nokia, а затем компания Digia придумали [QDialog](https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-dialogs.html) от которого можно наследоваться и реализовать все свои фантазии.

В частности, от QDialog наследуются следующие классы:

`QColorDialog, QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QInputDialog, QMessageBox, QProgressDialog, и QWizard`

И, заметьте, у каждого своя специфика и назначение. Поэтому я вам рекомендую заглянуть
в [документацию](https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-dialogs.html), почитать про QDialog и подумать над решением вашей собственной задачи при помощи данного класса, а может быть и другого